# Copy Database after starting swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

this is my first DB Project, so i am facing some issues. Hopefully you can help me!
I am using FMDB to have access to an existing DB. When i try to execute a simpel Query like "Select * From films" it returns stuff like "no such table". I looked into the folder of the IPhone Simulator and found the DB, but it was empty. My next Step was, to include this Method:

```
func copyDatabaseIfNeeded() {
    // Move database file from bundle to documents folder

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let documentsUrl = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                        in: .userDomainMask)

    guard documentsUrl.count != 0 else {
        return // Could not find documents URL
    }

    let finalDatabaseURL = documentsUrl.first!.appendingPathComponent("foo.db")

    if !( (try? finalDatabaseURL.checkResourceIsReachable()) ?? false) {
        print("DB does not exist in documents folder")

        let documentsURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("foo.db")

        do {
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: (documentsURL?.path)!, toPath: finalDatabaseURL.path)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Couldn't copy file to final location! Error:\(error.description)")
        }

    } else {
        print("Database file found at path: \(finalDatabaseURL.path)")
    }
}
```

But this Method is not working. Im calling it from DidFinishLaunching.

This is the error message:

```
OverBurned/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5EAE004-A036-4BD5-A692-C25EF3875D25/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5ABA8D38-7625-4F98-83E9-4266A3E5B6B0/GameOne.app/foo.db, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000053230 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

()

Am i using the wrong Method or is implemented wrong?

Comment: I found it easier to use sqlite.swift library for my first DB app instead of FMDB. Might be worth checking out.

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the code you posted. And you really need to spend some learning how to deal with optionals properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is clear. There is no `foo.db` in your app's resource bundle.

You do have lots of issues with the code you posted.

1. Your code to get the path to `foo.db` is far from ideal.
2. You do not properly deal with optionals.
3. Your variable names need to be improved. Example - the 2nd `documentsURL` implies it is a `URL` referencing the "Documents" folder. It is actually a `URL` to a file in the resource bundle.
4. There is no need for `NSError`.

Here is how I would write this code:

```
func copyDatabaseIfNeeded() {
    // Move database file from bundle to documents folder

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    guard let documentsUrl = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }

    let finalDatabaseURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("foo.db")

    do {
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: finalDatabaseURL.path) {
            print("DB does not exist in documents folder")

            if let dbFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "foo", ofType: "db") {
                try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: dbFilePath, toPath: finalDatabaseURL.path)
            } else {
                print("Uh oh - foo.db is not in the app bundle")
            }
        } else {
            print("Database file found at path: \(finalDatabaseURL.path)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Unable to copy foo.db: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that the DB would be copied by default. It took me a long time to find out that i am wrong. So i just copied the method from another post. It is not mine. But thanks a lot for you method! I tried it but the error is sadly the same. Is there something, i have to look for during importing the DB except the checkbox copy?

Comment: Using the code I posted, what happens exactly? Which message appears?

Comment: OverBurned/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5EAE004-A036-4BD5-A692-C25EF3875D25/data/Containers/Data/Application/C15B1423-7531-4F90-B726-AAB5528A656F/Documents/foo.db, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000052300 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
()

Comment: See my update. You want to use `FileManager fileExists` to see if the file exists or not.

Comment: You are a genius! The `.checkResourceIsReachable` was really the Problem. Now, everything works fine